# Error while sending request from web-server to game-server

Tags: node.js, pomelo

Error: not opened at WebSocket.send

I have a piece of code on node server where i send the data to the game-server of my game.

```
pomelo.init({
    host: rootTools.connectorHost,
    port: rootTools.connectorPort,
    log: true
  }, function () {
    var playerData = {any data of key value pair};
    pomelo.request('connector.entryHandler.broadcastPlayer', {data: playerData, route: 'update', playerId: data.playerId}, function (err, data) {
      console.log(err, data);
      pomelo.disconnect();
    });
  });
```

While running on production there is a error Error: not opened

the console screenshot is -

> [pomeloclient.init] websocket connected!
>   /home/digvijay/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:181 else throw new
>   Error('not opened'); ^
>
> Error: not opened at WebSocket.send
>   (/home/digvijay/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:181:16) at send
>   (/home/digvijay/node_modules/pomelo-node-client-websocket/lib/pomelo-client.js:180:14)
>   at Object.handshake
>   (/home/digvijay/node_modules/pomelo-node-client-websocket/lib/pomelo-client.js:242:5)

The pomelo.init worked well as on consoles the websocket is connected.

I didn't get the issue in the code. Kindly describe the expected cause and suggestions on how to resolve is any.